# REST API to auto generate a value using post

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I will need to create an API that will pass auto generated values to the Text box on the page. Project name is the field we will be passing the auto generated fields. [image]

I am new to Web API but I have created the REST API to query a Database and return values using get method. So here everytime the End point is called it should return the auto generated Project name. How to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in REST you'll want to use the `POST` verb whenever you need to **create a resource** and **let the server choose its name**. In the HTTP implementation of REST, the server will return the resource name (which is a URI) in the `location` Header.

If you want to use this approach, this is the way to follow.

The parameters required for the name generation are significant to understand whether this is the best approach or not (is it the case to create a project resource holding these parameters? Does it make sense?). For example, if you need **to create a new project** you could use the following design:

`POST http://authority/rootpath/projects`

```
{    
   name:"prj name",
   relevance:"high",
   dependencies: [...]       
}
```

expecting to have back in the response Headers

```
location: http://authority/rootpath/projects/prj_name123
```

However, maybe you don't want to create a project at all and you just want ask the server for a new name. In this case I think that `GET`ting is a more coherent approach.

```
GET http://authority/rootpath/projectNames?a='some'&b='useful'&c='parameters'
```

this request will be followed by a response holding a resource representation like so

```
{    
   name:"prj name"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is possible to generate the Project name without getting any input parameters.

Comment: from this comment I understand that you don't need to generate a project resource so the POST strategy *as described above* is worthless. The best thing to do is adopt the GET approach. You are not forced to use the query params if you don't need them. If you *really* want to use the POST, you should design a `projectName` resource to be submitted to the server to `/rootpath/projects` and expect this resource name in the `location` Header *or* in the body.